# Select latest 2 articles, but only from given category

Tags: mysql

Before anyone says I should be using the built in WP functions to do this - its a Perl script, so I can't ;) I'm trying to just grab the latest articles so I can show them in a different CMS. I have the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts
WHERE 1=1 AND post_type = "post" AND post_status = "publish"
ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 2
```

This works fine for grabbing the latest 2 published posts - but I also need to filter out based on the category as well (I don't want 1 of the categories included). So I have:

```
SELECT p.*, t.term_id
FROM wp_posts p
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships rel ON rel.object_id = p.ID
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tax ON tax.term_taxonomy_id = rel.term_taxonomy_id
LEFT JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = tax.term_id
WHERE 1=1 AND post_type = "post" AND post_status = "publish" AND t.term_id != 56
ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 2
```

This is ignoring the category_id 56. However, it has the undesired effect of including what appears to be duplicates, or maybe even drafts:

[image]

Out of view, the first row has a term_id value of 3, and the other is 9. I'm a bit new with the whole terminology relationship, so I'm really too sure how this works.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Cheers

Andy

Comment: Display post on a different application? I think this is a perfect use case of WP REST API, and you can use it in a Perfl script.

Comment: @cybmeta Thanks for the suggestion. I wasn't aware of the API. I'm trying it with: https://domain.net/blog/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/ . This loads the results, but it doesn't do it as JSON. Am I missing something / a template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code-

```
SELECT p.*, t.term_id
FROM wp_posts p
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships rel ON rel.object_id = p.ID
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tax ON tax.term_taxonomy_id = rel.term_taxonomy_id
LEFT JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = tax.term_id
WHERE tax.taxonomy = 'category' AND post_type = "post" AND post_status = "publish" AND t.term_id != 56
ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 2
```

Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: Could you add some explanation of what is different from the code of the question and how it solves the issue? Jsut dumping code is not very good answer. This way a lot of users will be able to udnerstand the answer, and to learn, even user with low SQL knowledge.

Comment: Thanks - that did the trick :) I'm also going to have a look into the API as well though, as that will be a bit more future proof in case anything major changes.